# Generic Grid Filler Extension Method

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, extension-methods, sharing

I've written this method about 3 times now and I'm pretty certain I'm not going to be done writing it for some time :

```
    public void PopulateField( ) {
        this.grdNameField.ColumnDefinitions.Clear( );
        this.grdNameField.RowDefinitions.Clear( );
        this.grdNameField.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).ToList( ).ForEach( VB => VB.Child = null );
        this.grdNameField.Children.Clear( );

        for ( int x = 0; x < Settings.Default.PlayerCount; x++ ) {
            Viewbox VB = new Viewbox( ) { Child = this.PlayerNamers[x], Stretch = Stretch.Uniform };
            this.grdNameField.Children.Add( VB );
            Grid.SetColumn( VB, x % Math.Max( 3, ( int )( Math.Ceiling( Settings.Default.PlayerCount / 5.0D ) ) ) );
            Grid.SetRow( VB, x / Math.Max( 3, ( int )( Math.Ceiling( Settings.Default.PlayerCount / 5.0D ) ) ) );
        }

        int
            ColumnCount = this.grdNameField.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).Max( VB => Grid.GetColumn( VB ) ) + 1,
            RowCount = this.grdNameField.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).Max( VB => Grid.GetRow( VB ) ) + 1;

        for ( int x = 0; x < ColumnCount; x++ )
            this.grdNameField.ColumnDefinitions.Add( new ColumnDefinition( ) { Width = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );

        for ( int x = 0; x < RowCount; x++ )
            this.grdNameField.RowDefinitions.Add( new RowDefinition( ) { Height = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );
    }
```

I've finally noticed that the difference between the three functions is only what the grid is being filled with : A generic list of objects List (and on occasion, what the Viewbox Stretch property is being set to).

I want to write a generic method to replace these three (and all future) methods and I have an idea how to do it...

Answer (score -1):

As I was typing this question it struck me that I could go further than just writing a generic method to handle populating Grids - I could write an extension method, and that's what I did :

```
    public static void Populate<T>( this Grid Parent, List<T> Children, Stretch ViewBoxStretch ) where T : UIElement {
        Parent.ColumnDefinitions.Clear( );
        Parent.RowDefinitions.Clear( );
        Parent.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).ToList( ).ForEach( VB => VB.Child = null );
        Parent.Children.Clear( );

        for ( int x = 0; x < Children.Count; x++ ) {
            Viewbox VB = new Viewbox( ) { Child = Children[x], Stretch = ViewBoxStretch };
            Parent.Children.Add( VB );
            Grid.SetColumn( VB, x % Math.Max( 3, ( int )( Math.Ceiling( Children.Count / 5.0D ) ) ) );
            Grid.SetRow( VB, x / Math.Max( 3, ( int )( Math.Ceiling( Children.Count / 5.0D ) ) ) );
        }

        int
            ColumnCount = Parent.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).Max( VB => Grid.GetColumn( VB ) ) + 1,
            RowCount = Parent.Children.Cast<Viewbox>( ).Max( VB => Grid.GetRow( VB ) ) + 1;

        for ( int x = 0; x < ColumnCount; x++ )
            Parent.ColumnDefinitions.Add( new ColumnDefinition( ) { Width = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );

        for ( int x = 0; x < RowCount; x++ )
            Parent.RowDefinitions.Add( new RowDefinition( ) { Height = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );
    }
```

Mind you, not everyone will want to throw their children into boxes, and likely this (or something close enough has already been done), but I thought I would like to share this.